Particles not using animated rotation
I've been trying to make turrets in blender that emit particles and use locked track for easy aiming, but when an object emitting particles uses locked track to aim, the particles will emit using the orientation the object is in per frame, instead of interpolating.
What it looks like when the emitting object uses locked track.

What it looks like when the emitting object has a rotation animation.

